# foreach loop through specific $request

Tags: php, foreach

I have a form that has several input types all that need to be a handled differently. I did a loop to name them like so in the form:

```
product-0-length
product-0-size
product-1-length
product-1-size
product-2-length
product-2-size
```

On my processing php (where the form info gets sent) I want to iterate a loop to handle say size different from length. My thought was this but no luck:

```
<?php  
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_REQUEST['product-'.$i.'-length'] as $key => $val) {
        //style or do what I need with the length information for each product 
        echo '<li>'.$key.'='.$val .'</li>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should use HTML arrays, it would make your life much easier

Comment: how do you mean @RobbieAverill

Comment: @RobbieAverill There are no "html arrays". What you probably refer to is using input names following the naming scheme `product[1][length]` which will, when get submitted in a form, get translated into a php array on the server side. On the client side these are ordinary strings, not arrays.

Comment: @arkascha skip the `1` in your example and you've got a winner.

Comment: @RobbieAverill That was an example. You should _not_ skip the number for the task at hand (so you should _not_ use `product[][length]`) here. Though syntactically possible it makes no sense for the task the OP asks about.

Comment: @arkascha I totally disagree as having numeric keys coded in just adds more work to maintain your DOM. This is where I depart...

Comment: @RobbieAverill please note that the OP generates the input fields in a loop, so that is just not true. In addition, when skipping the number you would create a new array entry for each input field, _which clearly is_ not _what the OP wants._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments above you could use a different naming scheme for your input fields. Take a look at this example for the form creation:

```
<?php
foreach ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"product[$i][length]\">\n";
  echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"product[$i][size]\">\n";
}
```

When submitting this form the server will translate the notation into a php array which is a very convenient thing. You can simply iterate over that array:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $key=>$product) {
  echo "<li>Length of product $key: " . $product['length'] . "</li>\n";
  echo "<li>Size of product $key: " . $product['size'] . "</li>\n";
}
```

*Note that this is a very primitive example, all error checking and the like is missing to keep things crunch. Also I did not test this code here, it is just meant to point you into the right direction, but I hope there are not too many typos in there...*